# Plugin Manager no plugins available in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I  need this for git plugin but there is no options in the dropdown of manage jenkins. I did manage jenkins-> manage plugins but there is no option the error I got is

There were errors checking the update sites: UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io. Please help me

Comment: Your jenkins instance does not have internet access.

Comment: Check firewall configuration and internet access.

Comment: Also check if you need to configure a proxy server, which is common in corporate networks.

Comment: I already have internet access and I am not using any organization proxy for that matter of fact. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Try replacing `https` with `http` or vice versa under Manage **Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced > Update Site > URL >** `https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json`*

Comment: And I have already put https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json in the update site

Comment: I change https to http but problem still persists .

Comment: Please help me regarding this problem..

Comment: Try to rule out if Jenkins is the cause. Can you `curl` the update URL from a shell session on the machine, where Jenkins is installed?

Comment: What is Curling the update ? will you plz elaborate ?

Comment: Was there a resolution for this?

Answer (score 1):

for centOS :

Disable and stop the firewall on my Centos Host

sudo systemctl disable firewalld

sudo systemctl stop firewalld

Then, restart docker:
sudo service docker restart